# Better visualisation with ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have a function that I have plotted with the `Contourplot3D` using

```
func = -2 (2 x^3 + y^3 + 2 z^3) \[Pi] + 1/18 (8 x + y + 8 z) \[Pi]^3;

blue = ColorData[100, "ColorList"][[3]];

curve = ContourPlot3D[func == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, \
ContourStyle -> Directive[blue, Opacity[0.95]], Mesh -> None, \
Lighting -> ({"Directional", White, #} & /@ Tuples[{-1, 0.5}, 3])]
```

The generated result looks like this
[image]

I have tried various colors and lighting; however, the outcome is not satisfactory as from this angle, one may recognize one hollow in the middle of the figure.
Do you have any suggestions for better visualization of the middle part of this figure in which three hollows form?

Comment: What is wrong with `ContourPlot3D[func == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}]`?

Comment: In principle, there is nothing wrong! My concern is that I should report these figures in a manuscript and thus should optimize the visualization for those who can't rotate the 3D figure. Hence, I am looking for better visualization of my function.

Comment: I think the 3D structure is better displayed with a mesh than only with lighning.

Comment: I see! Do you have a suggestion for a combination of meshing and coloring?

Comment: Try e.g. Lighting -> "Standard" or Lighting -> ThreePoint"

Comment: Thanks! Lighting->"ThreePoint" helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe use `StippleShading`.

```
ContourPlot3D[func == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[blue, StippleShading[]], 
 Lighting -> ({"Directional", White, #} & /@ Tuples[{-1, 0.5}, 3])]
```

[image]

Or

```
ContourPlot3D[func == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][z]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Could you also add `ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"` to your code?

Comment: @Shasa Do you mean `func = -2 (2 x^3 + y^3 + 2 z^3) \[Pi] + 1/18 (8 x + y + 8 z) \[Pi]^3;
ContourPlot3D[func == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][z]]]`?

Comment: Yes! This looks way better than my version. If you could add this to your answer, I would be happy to accept that. Thanks!